Measuring emission coefficient through stimulated emission e.g. for CAT scan of emission coeffcient?
Emission coefficient is probably usually measured by spontaneous emission - are there approaches, literature to measure it through stimulated emission instead, like in STED microscopy?
For example absorption coefficient is naturally measured by placing target between laser and detector - performing CPT transform of this setting like below, suggests how to analogously measure emission coefficient - is it a valid, used way?
If possible, it could e.g. allow CAT scan for 3D mapping of emission coefficient (e.g. of autoluminescent molecules like NADH for medial applications), while standard do it for absorption coefficient - is it considered in literature?
What are other approaches to measure emission coefficient?
Update: one approach is through McCumber relation from absorption coefficient and Boltzmann distribution, but will rather not work e.g. for autoluminescence.
Usually the number of emitting molecules is much lower than absorbing, so below scanner might have better transparency (?)

